# In VS Code online how do I get back to the address bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I use Visual Studio Code in the browser (for me that’s always at GitHub.dev) I can’t figure out to put the focus in the address bar using a keyboard shortcut ( typically I want to do this so I can get back to GitHub.com). Usually I use CMD-L to put the focus in the address bar but it seems that gets intercepted by VSCode.
Surely I can’t be the only one frustrated by this? And idea how to put the focus back in the address bar using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I'm frustrating the same problem. I now use "Open Permalink in Github" from the command pallet but there might be a better way.